# show that $C([0, 1])$ is not a Banach space with the given norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C([0, 1])$ be the space of all continuous real-valued functions
on the interval $[0, 1]$, with norm

$\displaystyle\lVert f\rVert_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^2 \,dx}$.

I need to show that $C([0, 1])$ is not a complete space (i.e. a Banach space) with respect to this norm.

Comment: Let $f_n$ be the function whose graph consists of the straight line segments joining $(0,1)$, $(1/n,0)$, and $(1,0)$. Show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy under your $2$-norm. Note that its only possible limit is not in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: "The only possible limit is not in $C[0,1]$"? - How do you define a limit if it is not in the space of reference?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Perhaps I should have said: "If it converged in $C[0,1]$, it would have to converge to its pointwise limit. But the pointwise limit is not in $C[0,1]$, so..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, which is not always answered rigorously. You should construct a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent. One such is
$$
f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text{if} & x\in \left[0,\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{n}\right), \\
\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{n}{2}(\tfrac{1}{2}-x) & \text{if} & 
x\in \left[\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{n}\right],\\
0 & \text{if} & x\in \left(\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{n},1\right].
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Clearly, all the $f_n$'s are continuous, and is it not hard to show that $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

The delicate part (which I am not answering in detail) is how to show that it does not converge, with respect the this norm, in $C[0,1]$.

Hint. If it did converge, say to $f$, then show that $f(x)=1$, for $x<½$ and $f(x)=0$, for $x>½$, and hence discontinuous at $x=½$.